# Hash of hex value is different between Solidity and Ethers

Tags: solidity, javascript, ethers.js, keccak

Assume you have a string of hex data you want to hash.

In Ethers:

```
ethers.utils.keccak256("0x1234");

// "0x56570de287d73cd1cb6092bb8fdee6173974955fdef345ae579ee9f475ea7432"
```

In Solidity:

```
function hasher() external pure returns(bytes32) {
  return keccak256('1234');
}

// "0x387a8233c96e1fc0ad5e284353276177af2186e7afa85296f106336e376669f7"

function hasher() external pure returns(bytes32) {
  return keccak256('0x1234');
}

// "0x1ac7d1b81b7ba1025b36ccb86723da6ee5a87259f1c2fd5abe69d3200b512ec8"
```

Why aren't these hashing to the same value?

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by [Sush](https://twitter.com/0xSush/status/1501147137031413760), the Solidity values being passed are a string, not a hexadecimal value. As a result, what's being hashed in the question is the string of the characters `1234` or `0x1234` above, *not* the hexadecimal value `0x1234`. If you wanted to hash the value `0x1234`, you could use `hex'1234'`:

```
function hasher() external pure returns(bytes32) {
  return keccak256(hex'1234');
}

// 0x56570de287d73cd1cb6092bb8fdee6173974955fdef345ae579ee9f475ea7432
```

If this isn't a case where you're able to hardcode the literals, pass them in as `bytes`:

```
function hasher(bytes memory value) external pure returns(bytes32) {
  return keccak256(bytes(value));
}

// hasher("0x1234") = "0x56570de287d73cd1cb6092bb8fdee6173974955fdef345ae579ee9f475ea7432"
```